# Read a text file in android

Tags: android, file

I want to read a text file in android. I am trying this code.

```
public class GIF_Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gif_);
        try {
            PlayWithRawFiles();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                         "Problems: " + e.getMessage(), 1).show();
        }
    }

    public void PlayWithRawFiles() throws IOException {      
        String str="";
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();          
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.abc);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        if (is!=null) {                         
            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
                buf.append(str + "\n" );
            }               
        }       
        is.close(); 
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                buf.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              


    }

    }
```

But instead of getting the file displayed on the screen the file is being toasted. Please help me to read the full file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                buf.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Is where you toast the file to the screen.

Where do you wanna put it? Can you show the `activity_gif_.xml` ?

Answer (score 1):

The file is getting toasted because *you're toasting* the file.

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                buf.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Use a TextView or a TextArea to display the file contents instead of using a toast.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(<id of the textview>);
tv.setText(buf.toString());
```